# Set contains v/s Set add methods for duplicate object

Tags: java, hashmap

Writing a method to find a duplicate key generated for a record. For example hash of multiple columns of CSV. This hash I am storing in a HashSet to find a duplicate. Wanted to know which method of HashSet is more efficiency. boolean [add](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#add(E))(E e) or boolean [contains](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#contains(java.lang.Object))(Object o). 
Anyone has run a performance measure for the same?

From reading the document of the internal implementation of HashSet as it implements map internally. It can efficiently find duplicate addition. Opening the question for expert opinion/suggestion with proof.

Comment: You don't choose methods based on how efficient they are. You choose them based on what they do. If you want to add an object to the set, you use add(). If you want to test if the set contains an object, you use contains.

Comment: Please look at [help/on-topic] and [ask]. Questions are not supposed to be "let's open a discussion", or requests for opinions.

Comment: @RealSkeptic you can edit my question to standards if you like. I am more interested in the answer then documenting a perfect question.

Comment: I think your approach is wrong, if you hash multiple columns and store the hash in HashSet you may run in collision, this means different records with different values in columns may have  the same hash. Thus it'll be duplicate and here is the error. as for performance you can read the javadoc of HashSet: This class offers constant time performance for the basic operations (add, remove, contains and size), assuming the hash function disperses the elements properly among the buckets